# Export a complete account history CSV that includes NFTs

Tags: nft, blockexplorer, tzkt

I need to prepare my taxes and discovered TzKT and its ability to export a statement in the form of a .csv file.

While that is super helpful it seems to not include any NFTs even though they show up on the TzKT website and are included in the "Operations" tab for example.

Is there a way to generate a complete statement that also includes NFTs?

And if not, is there some other way to export it somewhere else?

I really have done quite a bit of NFT trading and entering it all manually would take me days...